# Linear Algebra, Determinant of symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $A = [a_{ij}]$ be a square matrix of order n whose entries are given as follows. For
$1 \leq i, j \leq n$ we have
\begin{equation}
a_{ij} = \begin{cases}
ij &\text{ if } i\neq j\\
1+ij &\text{ if } i =  j
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Evaluate the determinant of $ A$( in terms of $n$).

Comment: Do you mean $a_{ij}=ij$ for $i \neq j$ ?

Comment: Yes, i meant i ≠ j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the $i^\text{th}$ row of $A$ as $A_i=\begin{bmatrix}
i&2i&\ldots&(i-1)i&i^2+1&i(i+1)&\ldots&ni
\end{bmatrix}$.

Therefore, $A_i-iA_1=\begin{bmatrix}
-i&0&\ldots&0&1&0&\ldots&0
\end{bmatrix}$

Thus we get
\begin{align}
\text{det}(A)&=\begin{vmatrix} 2 & 2 & \ldots & n\\
-2&\\
-3&\\
\vdots&&I\\
-n\end{vmatrix}\\
&=2+2^2+3^2+\ldots+n^2\\
&=1+\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
\end{align}

Comment: How did you get 2+2^2+3^2+…+n^2 as det(A) ?

Comment: Expand the determinant with respect to the first row.

Comment: @LutzL You are correct. The author of the question has corrected it. Thanks both!

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix has the form $A=I+vv^T$ with $v_i=i$. A well-known [determinant formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) is
$$
\det(I+ab^T)=1+b^Ta,
$$
in this concrete case
$$
\det(A)=1+v^Tv=1+\sum_{i=1}^ni^2=1+\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6.
$$